# shopping cart with cookie and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopping-cart

i create a shopping cart with cookies and  jquery,

now my question is this:

when user click in order link,the order item is added to shopping cart and save in cookie,i dont know is this safe?because all data such as order ID and order price is save in cookie,

i think user can change this cookie value,for example change order price and reduct this,

I do not know this is true or not. if true What security do I need?

I guess store data in cookie and before redirect to bank account check this with database

However,i need know this cookis is safe or not?

Comment: Instead of using cookie, use session using server side language. Cookies are not that safe for e-commerce

Comment: you can store `productId` and `quantity`, don't store the price in cookie.